# How to use DataGridView BeginEdit for 3 columns in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, editmode

So I want the edit content to click first then the edit position in column 3, then I click second then the edit position in column 4, then ,then click third then the edit position in column 5.
or there is another way

Please guide me

Thanks

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = itrservice.GetLoadStocksoutdetailMaster.ToList()
        DataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically
    End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridView1.Columns("coledit") Then
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(3, e.RowIndex)
            DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(4, e.RowIndex)
            DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(5, e.RowIndex)
            DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)
        End If
    End Sub
```

RESULT FORM IN DATAGRIDVIEW280823

[image: RESULT FORM IN DATAGRIDVIEW280823]

Comment: The user can only edit one cell at a time so, if your code did anything, it would simply end up editing the last cell you specified. The code won't magically pause to wait for the user to edit a cell before carrying on with the code. Even if it could, it would still not know when the user was finished editing a cell unless they did something to indicate that.

Comment: What you would need to do is simply start editing the first desired cell in that row when the user clicks the `Edit` link. You would then have to catch an appropriate keystroke in that cell, e.g. `Tab` or `Enter`, and then explicitly start editing the next desired cell.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , thank for your reply, for this `What you would need to do is simply start editing the first desired cell in that row when the user clicks the Edit link. You would then have to catch an appropriate keystroke in that cell, e.g. Tab or Enter, and then explicitly start editing the next desired cell.` Please Guide me

Comment: Given that this is new information that you hadn't considered previously, you should put some thought into it for yourself first and make an effort to implement it. If you are unable to make it work, then you can either update this question or post a new question with the relevant information for that issue. Don't just sit and wait for others to do it for you.